# Maven does not run Cucumber tests

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit, cucumber

I have a Maven / Spring Boot 2.3.3 application with JUnit 5 and Cucumber (v6.5.1) tests.

The thing is that I can run OK either Unit and Integration tests via Maven, but it does not run Cucumber.

Cucumber Runner:

```
package cucumber.salad.api.integration.cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "classpath:features",
        plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/reports/cucumber", "json:target/cucumber.json", "usage:target/usage.jsonx", "junit:target/junit.xml" },
        extraGlue = "cucumber.salad.api.integration.cucumber.steps"
)
public class CucumberTest {
}
```

Cucumber Spring Context Config:

```
package cucumber.salad.api.integration.cucumber;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import cucumber.salad.App;
import io.cucumber.spring.CucumberContextConfiguration;

@ContextConfiguration
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = App.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class CucumberSpringContextConfig {
    
    @LocalServerPort
    protected int port;
}
```

Steps:

```
package cucumber.salad.api.integration.cucumber.steps;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import cucumber.salad.api.integration.cucumber.CucumberSpringContextConfig;
import cucumber.salad.api.service.DummyService;
import io.cucumber.java.en.*;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class SaladStepDefinitions extends CucumberSpringContextConfig {
    
    // steps here
}
```

I use Surefire and Failsafe in the Maven pom.xml:
https://github.com/danieldestro/cucumber-salad/blob/master/pom.xml

Here is the project repository: https://github.com/danieldestro/cucumber-salad

Command I run:

```
mvn clean test integration-test
```

But there is not a sign from Cucumber test execution.

I am missing anything or doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the latest Spring Boot version? I'm thinking it's a dependency mismatch with JUnit/Cucumber/Surefire

Comment: I am running on the latest Spring Boot (2.3.3). I will try with older versions.

Comment: Well, I tried Spring Boot 2.2.9 and 2.3.3 with Cucumber 6.4.0 and 6.6.0 and no luck here!

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem; when I ran the `mvn test` command the cucumber tests were not executed. I was using:

- spring-boot:2.5.0
- Java 11 (OpenJDK Zulu 11.0.11)
- Dependencies

  - cucumber-core: 6.10.4
  - cucumber-java:6.10.4
  - cucumber-junit:6.10.4
  - cucumber-spring:6:10.4

What I did was exclude the `junit-jupiter-engine` from the `spring-boot-starter-test` dependency.

```xml
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: correct. 'junit-jupiter-engine' dependency was the culprit.

Answer (score 7):

You're using `cucumber-junit` which integrates Cucumber with JUnit 4. You're also using JUnit 5. JUnit 5 can execute JUnit 4 tests through the `junit-vintage-engine`. However you've excluded this engine from your classpath.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Either include the the `junit-vintage-engine` or use the [`cucumber-junit-platform-engine`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/junit-platform-engine) instead of `cucumber-junit`.

Comment: Great. You saved the day. It works fine now. I pushed a new branch with the fix: https://github.com/danieldestro/cucumber-salad/compare/fixed

Comment: Starting with Spring Boot 2.4, JUnit 5’s vintage engine has been removed from spring-boot-starter-test. If we still want to write tests using JUnit 4, we need to add the following Maven dependency:
```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```
More: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing#1-junit-4

Answer (score 0):

If you use junit 5, all you have to do is to add the two cucumber dependencies (cucumber-java and cucmber-junit by excluding junit 4 from all your dependencies).

furthermore, import junit-vintage-engine so cucumber can use it.

Explanation :

If you import junit 4, all the tests with jupiter (junit 5) will be ignored, Or vice versa. You can test it by adding two classes with each version of junit (by adding @Test of each version on each class). Only one version will run.