# Running mvn on Cucumber Project Doesn't Run Any Tests

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit, cucumber

I have a Cucumber Java Project in Eclipse. When I try to run maven, either within eclipse or from the command line, no tests are run. But When I run the test in eclipse with Junit (right click -> run with Junit), it runs the test. I've researched many articles with this exact question, but none of the proposed solutions have fixed my problem.
Here's a description of my project structure:
The source files are located in src/main/java/linkedinlearning/cucumbercourse/*

The feature file is located in 2 different places (I'll explain why in a moment)

1. src/test/java/linkedinlearning/cucumbercourse/MenuManagement.feature
2. src/test/resources/features/MenuManagement.feature

The step definition file is located in:
src/test/java/stepdefinitions/MenuManagementSteps.java

The test runner file is located in src/test/java/testrunners/MenuManagementTest.java

I put the feature file in 2 different places because originally it was only in src/test/java/linkedinlearning/cucumbercourse/ but then I read online that it should go in src/test/resources/features, so I added it there as well.

Here is my pom file:

```
project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>linkedinlearning</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumbercourse</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Cucumbercourse</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>13</java.version>
        <java.home>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home</java.home>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.8.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-bom</artifactId>
                <version>7.2.3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <properties>
                        <!-- Work around. Surefire does not include enough
                             information to disambiguate between different
                             examples and scenarios. -->
                        <configurationParameters>
                            cucumber.junit-platform.naming-strategy=long
                        </configurationParameters>
                    </properties>
                    <includes>
                     
                    <include>MenuManagementTest.java</include>
                        
                </includes>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is my testrunner file MenuManagementTest.java

```
package testrunners;


import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;


@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features="src/test/resources/features",
        glue= "stepdefinitions",
        plugin= {"pretty"})
    
public class MenuManagementTest {
}
```

I set $JAVA_HOME to point to the correct JDK (/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home). Here is the result of running "mvn clean test" from the command line

```
jeffmartin@pc-jmartin ~/eclipse-workspace/cucumbercourse % mvn clean test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< linkedinlearning:cucumbercourse >-------------------
[INFO] Building Cucumbercourse 0.0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ cucumbercourse ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/jeffmartin/eclipse-workspace/cucumbercourse/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ cucumbercourse ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/jeffmartin/eclipse-workspace/cucumbercourse/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.0:compile (default-compile) @ cucumbercourse ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /Users/jeffmartin/eclipse-workspace/cucumbercourse/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ cucumbercourse ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ cucumbercourse ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to /Users/jeffmartin/eclipse-workspace/cucumbercourse/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ cucumbercourse ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.661 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-02-17T15:47:32-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there something obvious causing the test to be ignored?

Thanks

Comment: I saw another post, where someone mentioned they used maven-surefire-plugin version 2.19.1. So I tried switching the version from 3.0.0-M5 to 2.19.1, and now it works from the command line. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using JUnit 5 which is relatively new compared to Maven Surefire (which has a glacial development pace). So older versions of Surefire do not know how to run JUnit 5 tests yet.

However there are more puzzles. You're also using `cucumber-junit` which uses JUnit 4. But you don't have `junit-vintage` to run it with JUnit 5.

To avoid more confusion I would suggest *deleting* everything and starting over with https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton.

---

Maven only copies files from `src/**/resources` to `target/classes` and `taret/test-classes`. The `.java` files from `src/**/java` are compiled first, other files are mostly ignored.

So `.feature` files anywhere else are not copied and should be removed. When in doubt look at the contents of these folders.

I'd also suggest putting everything in one package and following the conventions for naming packages https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Note that the package is anything after  `src/**/java` and `src/**/resources`. Again when in doubt look at the `target/classes` and `taret/test-classes` folder.

---

> The source files are located in src/main/java/linkedinlearning/cucumbercourse/*

You're the 4th person I've seen using that course and get stuck.

Have a look at https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem while I was trying out Cucumber with Spring Boot REST. Finally, I was able to find the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/63635693. Basically junit-jupiter-engine had to be excluded from spring-boot-starter-test.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Here's my simple demo project: https://github.com/almarsimon/spring-boot-rest-cucumber